# Cl0sed Functions in Druid

Tags: string, binary

I'm trying to write a function that takes an 8-character binary string s and a positive number as an integer n, and prints a sequence of n binary numbers that increase according to my increment function.

How to I edit my function so that I can print these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of your other code is correct, there are five problems in your recursive code.

First, you're trying to use the value returned by the recursive call to `count`. But you have no `return` statements anywhere, so what could that value possibly be? So that `inc*cnt` is just going to try to multiply a string by `None` and raise a `TypeError`. If you look at your code, you have no need to return anything upward; `count` just takes some values, prints something, and calls itself again. So just ignore the `None` that it returns.

Next, you're trying to increment `s[-1]`. But `s` is a string, so that's just going to be the last character. You want to "increment" the whole string, right? So just pass `s`.

Next, you're trying to call yourself with `s[:-1]`. Again, `s` is a string; this is going to try to increment the first 7 digits of that string, then the first 6, and so on. Why would you want that? What you want to increment is *the value you just incremented*. That is, the same thing you just stored in `inc`. So just pass `inc`.

Next, you're doing the `print` *after* the recursive call. This means you're going to call the function that prints the second and later values, then print the first value. And so on. So they're going to show up in reverse order. If you want the first value first, `print` before the recursive call.

Finally, you clearly want the original value and the next 4 to get printed, not the next 5 without the original value. So you have to print out the pre-incremented value, not the post-incremented one.

So, the minimal change to your code is:

```
def count(s, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    else:
        inc = increment(s)
        print(s)
        count(inc, n-1)
```